# Centering FontAwesome Icons Horizontally

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, centering

I'm currently using FontAwesome, and am having a really hard time centering three icons horizontally in their container. I have tried doing it via positioning, also tried different display properties and even tried changing the container into a grid-box, but still I can't seem to get the required result.

```css
.icons {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Follow</h3>
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.icon { text-align: center; }` is all you need. `i` is an inline elemet and can therefor be aligned with text-align.

Comment: I tried that already, but still not working

Comment: what isnt exactly working, how does it look? hard to reprdocue here without the fontawesome library

Answer (score 0):

If

```
.icons {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

is not working, try to center the div with:

```
.icons {
 width: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 }
```

Of course you can give what width you want.